# What exactly does "Contains" mean in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

A pretty specific question if anyone knows the answer:  What exactly does "contains" mean, in the context of BoundingSphere1.Contains(BoundingSphere2)?

If i have a smaller sphere inside a larger sphere, does the smaller sphere "contain" the larger sphere as in the entirety of its volume is also the volume of the larger sphere?  Would that return a ContainmentType.Contains?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably means the same thing in VB.NET XNA, don't you think?

Comment: Sure, but i'm not using VB.NET. I'm using C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the MSDN page for the [BoundingSphere.Contains method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195373.aspx) that takes a BoundingSphere parameter:

> Checks whether the current 
>   BoundingSphere contains the specified 
>   BoundingSphere.

It returns a [ContainmentType enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.containmenttype.aspx) which

> Indicates the extent to which bounding
>   volumes intersect or contain one
>   another.

Specifically:

> Contains: Indicates that one bounding
>   volume completely contains the other.
>
> Disjoint: Indicates there is no
>   overlap between the bounding volumes.
>
> Intersects: Indicates that the
>   bounding volumes partially overlap.

If BoundingSphere1 is smaller than BoundingSphere2 then I suppose `BoundingSphere1.Contains(BoundingSphere2)` would return a *ContainmentType.Intersects* result instead of a *ContainmentType.Contains* result since it doesn't "completely" contain the other. On the other hand, `BoundingSphere2.Contains(BoundingSphere1)` should return *ContainmentType.Contains* since it "completely contains the other."

**EDIT:** I've updated my answer after reviewing the documentation again. Initially something sounded vague but now I think the emphasis in the enumeration details of "completely" and "partially" for Contains and Intersects, respectively, strengthen my expectations. I can't test this but this sounds reasonable.

Comment: That makes sense.  I wasn't sure how to read the "completely contains" portion as "Completely contains *the* volume of the other object" or "completely contains volume of the other object"

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this is how I am interpreting your assumptions.

BoundingSphere1 is a big circle.
BoundingSphere2 is a small circle.

Lets say BoundingSphere2 is entirely contained within BoundingSphere1.
From what I understand, you think BoundingSphere2 "contains" BoundingSphere1.

In actuality, BoundingSphere1 "contains" BoundingSphere2 because all of BoundingSphere2 is within BoundingSphere1.

You are basically trying to found out if a Sphere is within another Sphere.

so BoundingSphere1.contains(BoundingSphere2) will be true, but BoundingSphere2.contains(BoundingSphere1) would be false.

Comment: BTW, it returns an enum not a boolean. In the OP's case this will likely be ContainmentType.Intersects.

Comment: yeah sorry, I was just using true/false for clarity's sake. Guess I should have used the proper terms.